# get elemets from elemets in complex XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a complex xml and I need to get all the elements
`<sdnEntry>` containing the value "Individual" in the tag `<sdnType>`

this is my XML:

```
        string list = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
                        <sdnList xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd'>
                        <sdnEntry>
                            <uid>36</uid>
                            <lastName>AEROCARIBBEAN</lastName>
                            <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
                            <programList>
                                <program>CUBA</program>
                            </programList>
                        </sdnEntry>
                        <sdnEntry>
                            <uid>173</uid>
                            <lastName>ANGLO-CARIBBEAN</lastName>
                            <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
                            <programList>
                                <program>CUBA</program>
                            </programList>
                            </sdnEntry>
                        <sdnEntry>
                            <uid>2681</uid>>
                            <title>NAME1 SURNNAME1</title>
                            <sdnType>Individual</sdnType>
                            <programList>
                                <program>SDGT</program>
                            </programList>                         
                       </sdnEntry>
                       <sdnEntry>
                            <uid>2682</uid>
                            <title>NAME2 SURNNAME2</title>
                            <sdnType>Individual</sdnType>
                            <programList>
                                <program>SDGT</program>
                            </programList>
                            <idList>
                                <id>
                                <uid>1002</uid>
                                <idType>Passport</idType>
                                <idNumber>304555</idNumber>
                                <idCountry>Egypt</idCountry>
                                </id>
                            </idList>
                        </sdnEntry>
                       </sdnList>";
```

I have tried this so far, but it is not working:

```
        listXML.LoadXml(list);
        XDocument sndList = XDocument.Parse(listXML.OuterXml);
        var nls = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd");

        //TEST 1
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        var individ = sndList.Elements(nls + "sdnEntry")
                  .SelectMany(r => r.Descendants("sdnType").Where(e => (string)e.Element("sdnType").Value == "Individual"));

        //TEST 2
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        IEnumerable<XElement> individuals =  from element in sndList.Root.Elements(nls + "sdnEntry")
                                             where (string)element.Element("sdnType") == "Individual"
                                             select element;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var individualNodes = sndList.Root.Elements(nls + "sdnEntry")
                      .Where(e => e.Element(nls + "sdnType").Value == "Individual");
```